# Suppose we have $N_0$ with $s_n\leq t_n$ for all $n>N_0$. Prove if $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=+\infty$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}t_n=+\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose there exists $N_0$ such that $s_n \leq t_n$ for all $n > N_0$. Prove if $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n = +\infty$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} t_n = +\infty$.

Having been exposed to analysis for the first time recently, I find it very easy to get lost down blind alleys and lose track of quantifiers, etc. As such I'm not entirely sure if my proof is valid. Here is my attempt at the proof:

Let $M > 0$. First we observe since $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n = +\infty$, there must exist $N_1$ such that $n > N_1$ implies $s_n > M$. Let $N = N_0 + N_1$. Then, we see that $n > N$ implies $t_n \geq s_n$, and since we have $s_n > M$, it must be the case that $t_n \geq s_n > M$, and so $t_n > M$, which proves the limit in question.

Comment: I guess you'd like someone to comment on your work above? It looks O.K. You could explain/justify a little more, in particular that you use the fact that $s_n$ is unbounded to show that $t_n$ is unbounded.

Comment: Why was the question downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we have pick $N = \max (N_0, N_1)$ and then we have that $t_n \geq s_n$ for all $n \geq N$ and moreover, $t_n > M$ as desired.

Comment: Well, $N$ could be any integer greater than both $N_0$ and $N_1$ and OP's  choice of $N_0+N_1$ is also fine. I agree taking a max here is conventional, but as per limit definition it's not necessary.